# AngularJS populating the ng-options options from Java Map. (Sorting issue)

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, hashmap, ng-options

so I sorted the map in Java and then passed into Javascript with `new JSONObject(sortedMap);`.
This is already sorted by values. When passed in the Javascript file, if I hover the object in debug mode, I see

```
$scope.fruitList = {'AP' : 'Apple', 'GP' : 'Grape', 'LM' : 'Lemon'};
```

(sorry for the silly names.. just an example)

After this, in html file,

```
<select ng-model="fruit" ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in fruitList" >
    <option value="">----select----</option>
</select>
```

Because I want

```
<option value="">----select----</option>
<option value="AP">Apple</option>
<option value="GP">Grape</option>
<option value="LM">Lemon</option>
```

However, for some reason, the order is messed up when it comes out. I can't give you the actual output of my code since it's not with this example here. I don't know how exactly it is being ordered. 
I need the keys to be assigned as ng-model and the values to be displayed. So I don't think I can just extract the values, sort them and display them.
Any help would be appreciated! :)
In the link the order is correct. I'm not sure why but I think it's because I am defining the fruitList in the javascript file, not being passed as a message from Java file.

[http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/7921//](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/7921/)

Comment: you have added a wrng jsfiddle link

Comment: @Sajeetharan sorry, corrected it!

Comment: it displays in the correct ordr only

Comment: oops, I overlooked your code. You're code in OK. You can use "fruit" which holds the key. I deleted my answer.

Comment: @Sajeetharan It does in the link because the fruitList is hardcoded in the js file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it's because I'm using a JSON object, not JSON array. This way I can prevent the ordering to be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
 <select ng-model="fruit" ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in fruitList | orderBy:'key'" >
```

Comment: this doesn't work. And I think it's because it doesn't recognise key since the object is defined as (key, value) pair.